# Running apps on an actual device with distribution provisining profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'd like to run apps on an actual device with provisining profile for distribution.
But when I try to run apps on the above condition, the app abort with message "Could not launch the app".

The reason that I use provisining profile for distribution is that I'd like to test push notification for production.
Is that possible?

Comment: The type of distribution profile you want is an ad-hoc one, as their are different types of distribution profiles.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. However, first off, you need to provide UDID of your device you wish to run on in developer center. Then, in order to receive push notifications, you have to use provision profile, that has this included. Check all these and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to test production environment push notification then you should use ad-hoc distribution profile.

Create an Adhoc distribution profile for your app in provisioning profile. Download profile and install. Choose the Adhoc dist profile to code sign your app. Archive ipa and save for adhoc distribution. Copy ipa to your device and test push. It will use production push certs as opposed to development cert.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could upload your build to iTunes Connect and use TestFlight without actually submitting the app.